# unable to source an R file on mac

Tags: r

I am on mac, trying to source an R file, getting an error:

```
getwd() ##reveals the correct directory
```

I'm trying to do

```
source("test.R", local=TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in source("test.R", local = TRUE) : 
  test.R:1:2: unexpected input
1: {\
    ^

> Sys.info()                                                                                            
sysname "Darwin" 
release "10.8.0"
version "Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386"
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: "Is this a bug?" In your code? Yes.

Comment: Hi @joran. Im able to run it on the console, it works fine. but when I source the .R file, I get that error. Im unable to source the file.

Comment: Does the first line of your script begin with a `\\`? If it does then that is a bug.

Comment: when I save the file in mac using R, mac puts backslash characters to the R file, how do you prevent this?

Comment: So much missing information. What's in the file? How are you saving the file? From what application/editor are you saving it?

Comment: @joran, I am really sorry. I save it from the text editor. Text editor do not let me put an .R extension. So I go to the finder, rename the file with .R and backslashes appear all over the place. But If open this file in a text editor, I dont see any backslashes. How would you save to .R file in mac?

Comment: You need to be far more specific. "Text editor" is a category of computer applications of which there are many. Name the one you're using. Your claim that it "doesn't let you" use the extension .R is even more suspicious, since I've never seen a Mac app do that, pretty much ever.

Comment: it is called TextEdit, default editor. do you suggest any editor on mac that allows .R ext?

Comment: @user1471980: To avoid all these kinds of weird issues with getting R working when you're starting out, I'd recommend you download  [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) and start working with that. It will let you save .R files, quickly and easily run them in an R console, and has plenty of other features besides.

Comment: yes, Iam really sorry, it was really frustrating. I think I figured out. Thanks everyone. I use the R editor right from the window, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. The immediate issue is that you are trying to save your text document as an .rtf, which is what TextEdit does by default. If upon launching TextEdit you press Shift-Command-T, you can switch to plain text, and it will let you save the file with the .R extension.

But more generally, you really should not be using TextEdit. Either use RStudio (which is pretty great) or get a "real" text editor. Or even just use the R GUI.

Comment: TextEdit.app is actually a pretty solid editor. I have it set up to default to Plain text (set in the Preferences panel.) I now prefer the Mac GUI editing panels for the parens and brace matching, but used TextEdit for years. It is much better than the MS text editor, Notepad.

Comment: @DWin there is Notepad++ now :)